# Append PDF binary string to JS FormData

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, blob

```
var uploadData = new FormData();
uploadData.append('myFile', pdfData, fileName);
```

pdfData is coming from another server and outputs following on the console (excerpt):

> %PDF-1.3
> %¿÷¢þ
> 1 0 obj
> << /Metadata 3 0 R /Pages 4 0 R /Type /Catalog >>
> endobj
> 2 0 obj

so it's a PDF file in binary string (?).

Executing this code leads to following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.
```

When trying this:

```
uploadData.append('myFile', new Blob([pdfData], {type: 'application/pdf'}, fileName);
```

the request goes through but I get errors on the server side:

```
java.io.IOException: java.util.zip.DataFormatException: invalid code lengths set
```

So the PDF is sent not correctly, I assume.

How to encode pdfData correctly?

Answer (score 1):

check if your Blob instance contains a valid PDF file. Like this:

```
const blob = new Blob([data], { type: file.mime_type });
const blob_url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

and then create an  element to view it:

```
const embed_element = document.createElement('embed');
embed_element.setAttribute('src', blob_url);
embed_element.setAttribute('width', '800px');
embed_element.setAttribute('height', '2100px');
document.body.append(embed_element);
```

Does it show the PDF file correctly?

You should also check in your developer tools if the request is sent correctly. I think it should look similar to this (raw FormData in Chrome):

[image]